# IIS Application Request Routing configuration issue

Tags: iis-7

I am configuring Application Request Routing on IIS 7.0. More information could be found here,  http://www.iis.net/extensions/ApplicationRequestRouting

My development/deployment environment is, IIS 7.0 + Windows Server 2008. I have several web sites, each of them has stable and beta version, for example, I have beta version order system and stable version order system, the same as purchase system. I deployed the 4 systems on 4 different physical machines (machine name labvm1, labvm2, labvm3 and labvm4).

My requirement is, I want to have a common URL schema to access the different systems, like,

```
http://www.mycorp.com/order/beta
http://www.mycorp.com/order/stable
http://www.mycorp.com/purchase/beta
http://www.mycorp.com/purchase/stable
```

But since the 4 systems are deployed on 4 different physical machines with different machine/DNS name, how could I setup URL rewrite rule to map the same domain (http://www.mycorp.com) with different suffix to different physical online systems? BTW: I want end user in browser to see www.mycorp.com, other than expose internal machine name like labvm1.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, my instinctive response to this would be to use ISA Server or some other form of reverse proxy. I think even SQUID would do it (and SQUID is free). You just configure the reverse proxy rules so the requests get routed to the appropriate internal server. As far as the end use is concerned they just see your proxy server and they wouldn't be aware of all the stuff behind it.

If you want to stick with MS software then I'm 99% sure ISA 2006 (and probably earlier versions) using a web server publishing rule, which is in effect a reverse proxy.

JR

George2 asked why I wasn't recommending ARR: I'm sure ARR would work. However, while I've read the white papers, I've never used it in anger. If I want a reverse proxy my instinct tells me to get a reverse proxy rather than an IIS addon that does reverse proxying. If you might need the other tricks that ARR can do then obviuously choose ARR.

Comment: Why ARR is not recommended? :-)

Comment: I have a related question here, appreciated if you could take a look. http://serverfault.com/questions/43472/http-response-location-header-in-iis-7-0-arr

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is to create the redirects on the server hosting www.mycorp.com.  Create dummy websites for each of the four sites with a dummy default page as you 'll need this when going through the website creation wizard.  Then, going back into each website change the url path to a redirect URL of the actual server hosting the website.

But, before hand you will need to setup subdomains for each of the websites i.e orderbeta.mycorp.com, orderstable.mycorp.com.  Point these to each of the servers in DNS.
So when the end user enters www.mycorp.com/order/beta the redirect will take them to orderbeta.mycorp.com

UK

Comment: Creating dummy sites will make end user to see internal server name from browser address bar because of redirection is used.

Comment: I have a related question here, appreciated if you could take a look. http://serverfault.com/questions/43472/http-response-location-header-in-iis-7-0-arr